# See memory-use of Windows 10 Mobile when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm debugging an app on a Windows 10 Mobile device (Lumia 550) connected to my PC. I want to see the memory use like in Task Manager for the Phone. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate `Device Portal` on the phone (go to `settings`->`Update & security`->`For Developers`, activate the Developer Mode and next [Device Portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile). Now you see an URL where you can connect to the device portal.

[image]

Open a browser, navigate to the URL and [under Performace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#performance) you see data like you see in Taskmagr (CPU, GPU usage, used Memeory, transfered data over Wifi).

[image]

Maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Memory Usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210448.aspx) tool in Visual Studio 2015. There are also other tools to make performance profiling easy and painless.

For Windows Phone 8 specific profiling tools, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215908(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: "The diagnostic tools window does not support the current debugging configuration".

Comment: Looks like UWP apps running on Windows Phone are still not supported. That's a shame. You could take a look at some of the commercial offering like ANTS Memory Profiler or JetBrains dotMemory. If none or these work, you might want to roll out a simple memory profiling solution of your own. [GC.GetTotalMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good starting point.